# How to capture capitalized input letter which is capitalized by css: text-transform:capitalize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found the capitalized letter which is capitalized with css `text-transform:capitalize`  was not capitalized when captured by javascript. I wondered what's the easiest way to fix this?

Demo below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<input id="box" type="text" style="text-transform:capitalize">
<button id="showinput">type in something then press me</button>
</html>

<script>
$("#showinput").click(function(){
txt=$("#box").val();
alert(txt+"   as you can see, the first letter of each word is not capitalized!");
})
</script>
```

Comment: `text-transform` just changes the appearance of the text, not the actual value.

Comment: See my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS text-transform property only transforms what the user sees on the screen (as with all CSS properties). It does not interact with your JavaScript code. I would suggest applying a similar function to the string in JavaScript, such as [`_.upperCase`](https://lodash.com/docs#upperCase) from lodash.

Answer (score 1):

As McMath said, CSS text-transform doesn't interact with Javascript. Here is a solution that would give the result you are wanting by capitalizing the first letter in Javascript:

```js
$("#showinput").click(function(){
  txt = $("#box").val();
  txt = txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1);
  alert(txt+"   as you can see, the first letter of each word is capitalized!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <input id="box" type="text" style="text-transform:capitalize">
  <button id="showinput">type in something then press me</button>
</html>
```

Source: [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: If typing in multiple words like "hello world" the "w" is not capitalized with your kind code, but thanks. If typing starts with space, it not works also

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your js using regex

```js
    $("#showinput").click(function(){
    txt=$("#box").val();
    txt = txt.trim().replace(/\b\w{3,}/g, function (l) {
      return l.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + l.slice(1);
    });

    alert(txt+"   as you can see, the first letter of each word is not capitalized!");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <input id="box" type="text" style="text-transform:capitalize">
    <button id="showinput">type in something then press me</button>
    </html>
```

Test Cases: `Hello World`

**NOTE** This also handle the case when the entered text has space in between, style `text-transform:capitalize` handles the case of capitalizing each word.

Comment: With hug, if typing starts with multiple space, it not works then.

Comment: with a tighter hug!...:D good point do a trim then `txt.trim().replace(/\b\w{3,}/g, function (l) {
      return l.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + l.slice(1);
    });`

Comment: @ryanpika See my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/dsr0Lc7h/5/)**

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#showinput").click(function(){
txt=$("#box").val();
var newtxt=txt.split(" ");
var tmp=[];
for(i=0;i<newtxt.length;i++)
{
    tmp.push(newtxt[i].trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ newtxt[i].slice(1));

}
//alert(tmp.join(" "));//YOU CAN USE THIS ALSO
alert(tmp.join().replace(","," ")+"   as you can see, the first letter of each word is not capitalized!");//YOU CAN USE tmp.join(" ") also
})
```

**DESCRIPTION**

What I have tried is,
First get each word in array splitted by a `space`.
Then converting first letter of each word while trimming any space, then joining it with rest of word and getting it all in an array.

Then joining the array with `.join()` and then replacing `,` with a `space`.
I hope this will help you.

See fiddle for demo, its working as you said.